# What is the Red White and Blue suit in the Iron Man 3 trailer?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, marvel, iron-man-3

[image: Iron Man Three - Red White and Blue Suit]

What is the red white and blue suit shown in the [Iron Man 3 Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EjG-1U3wqA)?

Comment: @SachinShekhar So link to the question?

Comment: It looks like War Machine's armor, repainted. Has the USAF insignia, the large gun on his back, and apparently has a military color guard with him. My guess is it's James Rhodes.

Comment: @GabeWillard I think you're right. See my answer for a "zoom and enhance" on the image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you zoom in on that image you can see that it has "Lt. Col. James Rhodes" stenciled on the chest plate.

[image: Lt. Col. James Rhodes]

So, although that does look like the Iron Patriot armor from the comics, I think it's just War Machine with a new paint job.

Original image source: [First 'Iron Man 3' Poster and New Images Reveal Cool Armor and the Film's Villain](http://www.movies.com/movie-news/iron-man-3-images/10005)

Answer (score 15):

It is a reference to the [Iron Patriot Armor](http://marvel.wikia.com/Iron_Patriot_Armor) - `"full battlesuit patterned after the heroic images of Captain America and Iron Man"`.

As shown by Bill the Lizard above, it's Lt Col James Rhodes driving the armor.

[image: Iron Patriot Armor]

Comment: With the US Airforce insignia on the left forearm and what looks like a Vulcan cannon on the shoulder (Uncle Gaspacho anyone?) my guess is it's Rhodey, but that's just a guess.